# Exclude other scripts from debugging in PhpStorm

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug, phpstorm

When I start debugging and use another script on the server (e.g. [Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/)), i.e. a script outside the project that is not intended to be debugged, the script is paused by PhpStorm and following two warning appear:

- The script '[path to script]' is outside the project.
- Click to set up path mappings

Now, I have to press F9 (i.e. resume) to continue script execution. It is very annoying. Can I just exclude these scripts from debugging?

Comment: The technique I use to prevent this is running other scripts in a different browser (e.g. debug in Firefox, run other scripts in Chrome).

Comment: Hmm, it is a nice workaround. Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm .. I **wonder** what these options are for: `Settings | PHP | Debug | Xdebug | Force break at first line when no path mapping specified` and `... | Force break at first line when a script is outside of project` ...

Comment: @LazyOne That works. BTW? why didn't you post it as a response?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are few options just for that at **`Settings | PHP | Debug | Xdebug`**

- Force break at first line when no path mapping specified
- Force break at first line when a script is outside of project

There is also `Settings | PHP | Debug | Skipped Paths`, which can be useful in other scenarios when you want to ignore debug requests that were initiated for specific URL, but still debug other URLs. [Help page here](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/skipped-paths.html).